# How do I track repeated users that visit my website?

Tags: ip

How do I do that since almost everyone uses dynamic IP?
It changes everytime the users connect to the internet...
I wanna know if an user visited my site yesterday and today. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Integrate an analytics library like [mixpanel](http://mixpanel.com) and create javascript events to keep track of your users new or returning. That will be a better approach.

Comment: But how does it work? If I am not using IP to identify, what will I use?

Comment: Cookies is an option. You could also use an open source suite like Piwik (www.piwik.org)

Comment: check out the documentation [here](https://mixpanel.com/help/reference). Mixpanel allows to assign unique ids to your visitors and then keep track of them. You can also track independent events like clicking of a button etc. by using the method:

`Mixpanel.Track("Some Event")`